# Folder Dialog Box in a secondary monitor

Tags: c#

I have a folder dialog box and two different forms. The first form appears on the primary monitor while the second form appears on a secondary monitor. Whenever i ShowDialog the folder dialog box it appears on the secondary screen. How am i suppose to place it on the primary monitor? help please.. TNX A LOT!

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Look into the ShowDialog options.

Oh, and follow Darin Dimitrov's comment!